# Inverse of values using NSPredicate IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

```
NSArray *arrValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ABCD",@"ABCE",@"CDE"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd]%@",@"ABC"];    
NSArray *arrFiltered  = [arrValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I am aware that arrFiltered will contain the result ABCD and ABCE.

But, I want the result as CDE.

Is there a way to find the inverse of the predicate specified. ie., !(ABC)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `NOT` with predicate

```
NSArray *arrValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ABCD",@"ABCE",@"CDE"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@"),@"ABC"];    
NSArray *arrFiltered  = [arrValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: the code crash `reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SELF NOT CONTAINS[cd] %@"'`

Comment: check once before answer again your code is crash `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "NOT (CONTAINS %@)"'`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF !=[c] %@",@"ABC"];
```

> The `[c]` makes the equality comparison case-insensitive.

**Option-2**

```
    NSArray *arrValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ABCD",@"ABCE",@"CDE",nil];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF CONTAINS %@)",@"ABC"];
    NSArray *arrFiltered  = [arrValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

you get output as

[image]